# jQuery Ajax POST: Getting values out of response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Agenda/Template",
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { "templateId": templateSelect.options[templateSelect.selectedIndex].value },
        complete: function (data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                var value = data[key];
                alert("key: " + key, "value: " + value);
            }
        }});
```

I know that the return data has properties such as:

- Template ID
- Template Name
- URL

However, for the life of me, I can't GET to them.

My alerts show a lot of different keys ... Promise, Done, etc.  I just can't find my values.

Comment: what does data show when you do console.log to it?

Comment: @guradio list of key/value pairs, with things like "Promise", "Done", etc.  Can't find my data.

Comment: can you show in OP

Comment: Your code shouldn't return some "Promise" or "Done" response. We need some further information because the problem isn't in that code you have there. Try JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) and show us what that looks like

Comment: are you sure that  dataType: 'json',  required for this ajax?

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds ajax return promise object, so you can use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function:

```
$.when( 
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Agenda/Template",
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { "templateId": templateSelect.options[templateSelect.selectedIndex].value }
    })
).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    for (var key in data) {
        var value = data[key];
        alert("key: " + key, "value: " + value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Already tried that.  It gives me the same values.  I just need to GET to my data that's coming back.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it may helpful to you.

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Agenda/Template",
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { "templateId": templateSelect.options[templateSelect.selectedIndex].value },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data,function(key,value) {
                console.log("Key : " + key  +  " value : " + value);
            });
        }
 });
```